# How can I make vapor or "smoke" appear from a hot cup of tea?

Tags: smoke-simulation

Hello I'm new to this community and sort of a beginner to blender and on a process of making a scene with cup of tea in a living room. I made the tea, cup, plate, table, background... and finished the scene. The only thing that was left was to make the tea look hot and the only way to do that would be to create an evaporation effect or simply to add vapor coming out from the tea.

I figured the natural way to do this would be to add a smoke effect to it but even if I fiddled with settings to make it look like vapor, since I'm new to blender and dont really understand smoke effects I couldn't achieve the exact effect I'm looking for. If anyone could provide me the optimum settings to use for the smoke to make it look like a simple and light vapor instead of some kind of jet stream, I would very much appreciate it.

Thanks for taking your time to read my question.

Comment: Don't get me wrong, but this feels more like a tutorial request than a question. Check YT, there are tons of smoke tutorials and older ones about how to use billboards as smoke/mist/steam.

Comment: I assume a tutorial would be asking to go into detail on a subject which in this case would be asking "How to make a hot cup of tea". In case it was not clear I wanted to know the optimal settings which should almost always be the same for all hot drinks and the like so I can use it on my future projects as well. My pc is quite slow so changing the settings, baking the data and playing the animation over and over again would take quite a long time for me.

Comment: And yes I did look for answers around the internet but I found none for blender 2.8 that had the outcome I was looking for. Most were just for smoke animations, steam, mist...

Comment: How about this one: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dMeEPycxYiM it's for 2.79, but it should be fairly easy to upgrade. Watch it and if you have a specific question, feel free to ask it.

Comment: Search for mantaflow smoke on utube. You should play a lot with density and shaders.

Comment: You can also add a plane with alpha channel texture that simulates the smoke (if you don't need to animate the scene). Here some nice smoke textures: http://pngimg.com/imgs/nature/smoke/